# Local overrides in chrome – keep active while devtools are closed

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I really like the [local overrides feature in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides). While it is handy during development, I'd also like to use it **while my devtools are closed**. If this were possible, it could replace extensions that inject custom [css](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-css/okpjlejfhacmgjkmknjhadmkdbcldfcb?hl=en) or [js](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) into the page. (right now, after loading a page, overrides do not kick in until devtools have been opened at least once)

[After](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/local-overrides/) [some](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/02/27/make-permanent-changes-to-web-pages-with-chromes-overrides-dev-tool/) [digging](https://umaar.com/dev-tips/165-local-overrides-font-display/), I got the impression it's not possible though. Can somebody please confirm this? Is there any way to achieve the desired effect (custom js & css) without extensions?

Comment: Many devtools features can be invoked via protocol message in chrome.debugger API for extensions, but I don't see this one [listed](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/). There are no other methods.

Comment: In case of someone would want achieve this with chrome extension you can use:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/ddbjnfjiigjmcpcpkmhogomapikjbjdk

Comment: @KayceBasques's article about using the DevTools Without Opening DevTools appears to have gone down or been removed, here's the archived URL: https://web.archive.org/web/20200121044711/https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools-without-devtools