# Google Chrome Overrides dont load until I open the Devtoools (F12) menu

Tags: google-chrome, devtools

So I have some modifications to the text on a webpage. It is saved to overrides. And they work when I have the F12 menu open; and persist through refreshes and when I first go to the site.

But if the F12 menu is closed, my changes dont show until I open the menu and refresh the page.

How do I make the overrides show even if the F12 menu is closed?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: A duplicate (without answer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522923/local-overrides-in-chrome-keep-active-while-devtools-are-closed

Answer (score 2):

From comment on other [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522923/local-overrides-in-chrome-keep-active-while-devtools-are-closed):

> DevTools technical writer here. It's not possible to keep Local Overrides on while DevTools is closed. You might be able to script something with Puppeteer. See [Using DevTools Features Without Opening DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools-without-devtools).
>    – Kayce Basques Jul 27 at 21:06

So it looks like at this point it is not possible.